# How to access element itself when using foreach to add event listener

Tags: javascript, foreach, event-listener

When I create a couple of buttons using `forEach` then add an event listener to each and then try to access the element itself inside that listener, it just defaults to the last one.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <template id="button-template">
        <button></button>
    </template>

    <script src="./bug.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
const button_template = document.getElementById("button-template")

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    clone = button_template.content.cloneNode(true)
    btn = clone.querySelector("button")

    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        btn.style.display = "None"
    })

    btn.innerHTML = i.toString()

    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(clone)
    console.log("something")
}
```

In this example, I try to make each button remove itself. But all of them just remove the tenth one. How can I fix this? I already tried using `this` or `self`but I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one alternative, out of many: events have an [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) property, which points to the object to which the event was originally dispatched.

Thus, this is your code with that change:

```js
const button_template = document.getElementById("button-template")

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  clone = button_template.content.cloneNode(true)
  btn = clone.querySelector("button")

  btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.target.style.display = "None"
  })

  btn.innerHTML = i.toString()

  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(clone)
  console.log("something")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <template id="button-template">
        <button></button>
    </template>

  <script src="./bug.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, I believe the most important thing here is understanding why `btn` is always the last button: because you miss a `const` or `let` or `var`, your `btn` is a global variable, being constantly updated at each loop.

Thus, a simple `const` will fix this:

```js
const button_template = document.getElementById("button-template")

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  clone = button_template.content.cloneNode(true)
  const btn = clone.querySelector("button")

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn.style.display = "None"
  })

  btn.innerHTML = i.toString()

  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(clone)
  console.log("something")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <template id="button-template">
        <button></button>
    </template>

  <script src="./bug.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```